# Programatically fill PDF form fields in Browser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, forms, pdf

Basic scenario is that I need to programatically fill out a PDFs text fields that resides on a webserver. The fields will be mapped and filled out with data contained in a CSV. The PDF must be opened in the browser (browser control or ie/ff/chrome/etc) and edited in place. Cannot be downloaded, filled out, and uploaded (it must be filled out and submitted using the submit button in it; I've tried editing the buttons submission path to no avail).

Thus far I've put a web browser control on a form and made it navigate to the website, login, and load the PDF file. How do I interact with the PDF file thats open in the web browser control? Looking through various PDF libraries, they seem to mainly interact with a closed pdf located on the harddrive, make the modifications, and re-save it.

EDIT: Im very open to alternative solutions. I dont know if its possible, but if so - PDF based javascript on my machine that I run on the form? I can do this easily if I download it, but dont seem to be able to find a way to use PDFJS while its open in the webbrowser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid is it not easy to do what you want to do.  First you have to find the window handle of the PDF reader embedded in the WebBrowser control.  Here is sample code on how to do that:

```
    Public Function GetPdfViewerHandle() As System.IntPtr
    Dim tempHandle As System.IntPtr
    '--------------------------------------
    ' get handle to pdf viewer
    '--------------------------------------
    '--------------------------------------
    ' first check for the foxit reader
    '--------------------------------------
    tempHandle = FindChildWindow(WebBrowser1.Handle, "AfxWnd42s", "Reader", 1, True)
    If IntPtr.Zero.Equals(tempHandle) = True Then
        '---------------------------------
        ' if not foxit, check for adobe
        '---------------------------------
        tempHandle = FindChildWindow(WebBrowser1.Handle, "AVL_AVVIEW", "AVPageView", 1, True)
    End If

    Return tempHandle

End Function

Public Shared Function FindChildWindow(ByVal hParent As IntPtr, ByVal P_childClass As String, ByVal P_childTitle As String, ByVal P_count As Integer, ByVal p_recursive As Boolean) As IntPtr
     Dim hChild As IntPtr
     Dim className As String
     Dim title As String
     Dim cnt As Integer
     Dim tempPtr As IntPtr
     Dim Declare Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd1 As IntPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As Int32, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As IntPtr

     cnt = 0

     hChild = FindWindowExA(hParent, 0, Nothing, Nothing)

     While hChild.ToInt32 > 0

        If P_childClass Is Nothing Then
           className = GetClassName(hChild)
        Else
           className = GetClassName(hChild)
           If P_childClass.Length < className.Length Then
              className = className.Substring(0, P_childClass.Length)
           End If
        End If

        If P_childTitle Is Nothing Then
           title = GetWindowText(hChild).Replace("&", "")
        Else
           title = GetWindowText(hChild).Replace("&", "")

           If P_childTitle.Length < title.Length Then
              title = title.Substring(0, P_childTitle.Length)
           End If
        End If


        Debug.WriteLine("hwnd=" + Hex$(hChild.ToInt32) + ", className = " + className + ", title = " + title)
        If (String.Compare(className, P_childClass, True) = 0 And String.Compare(title, P_childTitle, True) = 0) Or (P_childClass = Nothing And String.Compare(title, P_childTitle, True) = 0) Or (String.Compare(className, P_childClass, True) = 0 And P_childTitle = Nothing) Then
           cnt += 1
           If cnt >= P_count Then
              Return hChild
           End If
        End If

        If p_recursive = True Then
           tempPtr = FindChildWindow(hChild, P_childClass, P_childTitle, 1, p_recursive)
           If IntPtr.Zero.Equals(tempPtr) = False Then
              Return tempPtr
           End If
        End If

        hChild = FindWindowExA(hParent, hChild.ToInt32, Nothing, Nothing)
     End While

     Return Nothing

  End Function
```

Once you have the window handle, there are a lot of different methods for finding the form fields.  If you know the order of things, you can simply start sending key commands to the pdf reader handle or use Spy++ to find the handles of the form fields to input data to them via the Win32Api SendMessageA function:

```
      Public Declare Function SendMessageA Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

                  asciiChar = CByte(Asc(data.Substring(0, 1)))
              rc = SendMessageA(hwnd, WM_CHAR, asciiChar, 0)
```

Good luck.

Comment: I should have added, the layout of the form will always be the same and I do already have the name of the textfields (thanks to iText#)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to submit the data with a button on the PDF just inspect the traffic submited and see what it sends then you can replicate with VB.NET and also will not even have to load the PDF document.